# How to loops over columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to change the activity column in the beaver2 dataset (prepackaged dataset in R) into a character vector such that the value 0 is replaced with "idle" and the value 1 is replaced with "active".
This is what I have tried so far but every entry is coming out as "idle" for some reason.

```
data("beaver2")
rownames1 <- rownames(beaver2)

for(i in 1:length(rownames1)){
  if(rownames1[i] == "0")
    beaver2$activ[i] = 'idle'
  else beaver2$activ[i] = 'active'
}
print(beaver2)
```

Comment: Don't use `gsub` for this since you are doing exact matching. Try with `ifelse` : `beaver2$new_col <- ifelse(beaver2$activ == 0, 'idle', 'active')`

Comment: the entire column is showing "idle" for some reason, any tips to fix this?